# variable and string apparently not matching

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

   <input onclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="first_name" value="First Name">
   <input onclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="last_name" value="Last Name">
   <input onclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="pwd" value="The Passcode">
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_">

   <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

</form>
```

PHP :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
  $pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);
  $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']); 

  // print_r($_POST);

if(is_null($text)) {

  debug_to_console('some fields empty');
  echo "<p class=\"warning\">* Your Message Did Not Contain Any Characters.</p>";

}

 else if($name === 'First Name'){

    debug_to_console('name isnt set');
  echo "<p class=\"warning\">* You Have Not Entered Your First Name Correctly.</p>";

  }

 else if($pwd !== 'XyZ'){

    debug_to_console('password not set');
  echo "<p class=\"warning\">* Passcodes Do Not Match.</p>";

} else {
```

Keeps returning 'password not set' even though the form input matches the variable. Used print_r and $pwd states XyZ.

tried removing onClick from the form input. I'm assuming this is a caps thing?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: use `strcmp()` for comparing string

Comment: Just a note: `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. Please switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: "password not set" or "Passcodes do not match"? You say you're getting one error while asking about another.

Comment: @Dan For as I have tried the code is running fine, I enter password XyZ it goes to else {} and when pass is not XyZ prints, "passcodes do not match". You wanted the same to work, if i m not wrong.!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I changed all mysql_ to mysqli_ and page displays Error: and also, please ignore what I have debug_to_console'd, that's just for myself.

Comment: @KartikA strange - could this be an issue with my host?

Comment: @DanFraser Yes maybe!, did you try restarting your host? is working now?

Answer (score 1):

Check $pwd with

```
var_dump($pwd);
```

I do believe $pwd is a string (because you use !== instead of !=) AND doesn't contain: XyZ

(if you didn't change the value in input field pwd, its value is still: The Passcode)

Comment: var_dump($pwd) displays: bool(false), even though i input XyZ as pwd.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string Returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error. You don't have to escape it already, just before using it in a sql staement is ok. But I strongly suggest you swicth over to PDO. This function (and others in the family) is deprecated